# Algorithm to compare 2D point sets of human body images

Tags: algorithm, api, computational-geometry

I am working on algorithm to compare two 2D point set. More specifically I have skeleton of two human body images as a 2D point set (25 points each, for example) and I want to find to what extent they are similar and which points, lines from one point to another or angles between lines makes images different.

Each point in the point set always corresponds to one part of human body. For instance point #2 corresponds to left shoulder and point #9 to left knee. All points are equally important.

I need to find whether point #2 of the first skeleton is in the similar position as point #2 of the second skeleton, and so on for all points in skeleton.

Point sets are not normalized.

I would like to know if there are exist any algorithms or API to solve my problem?

Comment: It seems you need to take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: To follow up on Someprogrammerdude, important information would be: Do the points have some semantics or do you want to treat all points equally important? Are there known correspondences, meaning, point 12 is always a "foot" or something like this? What do you mean by similar? There are a lot of similarity measurements for point sets/point clouds/graphs, that are all focusing on different aspects of similarity.

Comment: @SaiBot I have updated my problem explanation

Comment: @Sanzhar the most naive approach would be to use "sum of distances", which sums up the euclidean distances between points representing the same part of the body. Larger distance between two point sets means less similar. I know this is very simple, just want to find out if this satisfies your definition of similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there. If we suppose these two boundary shapes are a curve, a renown algorithm to find similarity between two curves is **Frechet Distance**. You can find more about it at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance).